# Typescript Cannot find module after migrating to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I recently migrated a small project from CommonJS to TypeScript, and I'm encountering a perplexing issue. The TypeScript compilation proceeds without any errors, yet when I run the server, I encounter the following error:

`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/ivan/Documents/Projects/api/src/v1/routes/userRoutes' imported from /Users/ivan/Documents/Projects/api/src/index.js`

Curiously, when I execute ls in the directory containing userRoutes, I can see that both the .ts and .js files are present. In index.ts, I'm importing userRoutes using the following statement:

```
import { userRouter as v1UserRouter } from './v1/routes/userRoutes';
```

Also inside `userRoutes` I have this export:

```
export const userRouter = router;
```

Comment: How are you compiling the project?